# .live working , but .on not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here in my code, when I am replacing `.live` with `.on` then it's not working? I am not able to identify the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    /*   Reading the data from XML file*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "photos.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function () {
                var path = $(this).attr('path');
                var width = $(this).attr('width');
                var height = $(this).attr('height');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
                var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
                var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
                $('#myImageFlow').append('<img src="' + path + '" id=' + id + '  height="' + height + '"  width="' + width + '" longdesc="' + longdesc + '" alt="' + alt + '"/>');
                imgArr[i] = description;
                imgFront[i] = longdesc;
                i = i + 1;
            });

            $(xml).promise().done(function () {
                console.log("image completed loading");
                $('img:lt(4)').removeClass('t2').addClass('t1');
                $('img:gt(3)').removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
                $('img#id12').removeClass('t1').addClass('t2');
                $('img#id1').removeClass();


                //alert('Front Initial Text is'+imgFront[1]);
                window.setTimeout(function () {

                    $("#front").html(imgFront[1]);
                    $("#front").css("background", "gray");
                }, 1500);
            });
        }
    });
    $.getScript('js/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js');
});

/*front div called when front or back is called */
$('#front').live('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    transitIt(this);
    //  alert('Front Clicked glob   e='+globe);
});


$('#myImageFlow img').on("click", function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called=' + clickEnabled);
});
```

Comment: what is the version of jquery?

Comment: why do you have `$('#front').live('click'`? Is `#front` ever removed from the document?

Comment: @ Mr_Green i am using jquery-1.7.1.js

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '#myImageFlow img', function() {
    // your code
});
```

---

References:

- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation

Comment: or just `$('#myImageFlow').on('click', 'img', function() {`

Comment: @Mr_Green If we sure that `#myImageFlow` is static on the page. Exactly right `;)`.

Comment: @NOX i have used simply to print alert but not working ... which js needed? m using 'jquery-1.7.1.js'????

Answer (score 1):

Your delegation is probably not defined properly:

```
$('#myImageFlow').on("click", 'img', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called=' + clickEnabled);
});
```

Assuming `#myImageFlow` is not removed from the DOM it's a good candidate for event delegation. Also, you were missing the `event` parameter in your click handler.

Comment: **+1** for `event` parameter `;)`. I didn't see it.

Comment: @Jack  #myImageFlow is div . on page load i am loadin images reading xml file. so for those elements i want to apply css.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
$('#myImageFlow').on("click", "img", function(event) 
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called='+clickEnabled);
});
```

or

```
$('html').on("click", "#myImageFlow img", function(event) 
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('htmlcalled image Clicked Called='+clickEnabled);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Any output from the console window?

Noticed you lack the (event) for the .on.

Besides that the on function uses bubbling to make it work. So use a part of your DOM tree that exists from the start, and put the children of that dom tree you want to be clickable in the brackets.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

> A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and > the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```